# Why we use (exp) rather than (log) in softmax?

Tags: neural-network, classification, logistic-regression, softmax

I don't know much about log and exp relationship. But, i am confused that, log is not used in softmax regression?

[Features to Probabilities section](http://blog.echen.me/2012/01/03/introduction-to-conditional-random-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

Exp is defined for all real values, while log isn't.

Any vector element equal or less than zero would lead to a numerical error or undefined behavior with the log function. exp does not have this problem.

To avoid the the undefined, you would either need to add a very small bias to all your elements. But how small should this epsilon be? What do you do with negative numbers. You may never expect a negative number but simply get it through a truncation error or coming very close to floating point representations (a value so small it ends up being represented as a small negative number).